# How to create a fixed version label visible on all screens with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I create in Flutter a fixed version label visible on all screens?

Here is an example of that version label:

[image]

Comment: use a `Stack` widget with two children: the bottom `MaterialApp` and top `Text`